# bash_completion does not work in dtach

Tags: bash, bashrc, profile, dtach

I start dtach from bash using the following command

```
dtach -c /tmp/dt0 bash
```

the problem is, before I started `dtach`, `bash_completion` worked. But once I start `dtach`, `bash_completion` does not work anymore.

I have to manually source the bash completion file

```
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

this line is `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`, but for some reason `dtach` does not source it properly.

Is there any way to make dtach use bash completion automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your `.bashrc` :

```bsh
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```